# Vim: How relieve PHP programmer's typing workload?

Tags: vim, php

For example, the most common code maybe is something like this:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$area = $_POST['area'];
$property = $_POST['property'];
$room = $_POST['room'];
$hall = $_POST['hall'];
```

Is there plugin/method could ease our pain?

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps you should go to stackoverflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a mapping that might help.

```
:imap \p <esc>diwa$<C-R>" = $_POST['<C-R>"'];
```

`<esc>` - takes you out of insert mode
`diw` - deletes the word under the cursor into the default register
`a` - puts you back into insert mode
`<C-R>"` - inserts the contents of the default register

When the mapping is done, you're left in insert mode, so you can just hit <enter> and continue with the next line.

To use this, type just the symbol name on a line and immediately follow it with `\p`.

You can put the mapping itself in your `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim` on Unix, or `~\_vimrc` or `~\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\php.vim` on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

[snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) to the rescue!

You could just create your own snippet, something along the lines of:

```
${1} = $_POST['${1}'];${2}
```

That'll allow you to type (e.g.) "pt", hit tab, fill in "title/price/area/etc" for the variable name, and have the POST value be automagically filled in with that value. Hit tab again to be taken to the end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

```
$props = array('title','price','area','property','room','hall');
foreach($props as $prop) $$prop = $_POST[$prop];
```

Comment: +1 for "Write better code"

Answer (score 2):

```
extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "p_");
# results in $p_title, $p_price, ...
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a "write better code" answer and perfectly answers the OP's question.